# Reading CSV using OleDbDataAdapter: duplicate columns ignored

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, oledbdataadapter

I have  the following code:

```
            using (var dt= new DataTable())
            {
                var connString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=\"{0}\\\"; Extended Properties=\"text;HDR={1};FMT={2}\"", dir, headers, format);
                var query = "SELECT * FROM [" + file + "]";

                    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
                    {
                        using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connString))
                        {
                            adapter.Fill(dt);
```

If there are duplicate columns in the .csv file it reads from, then that column will not be included in `adapter`

For some reason, duplicate columns are being treated as if the column does not exist.

Comment: When you say "not  be included" have you checked to see if the dt actually has a field with that same name and a number attached like [columnName1] in addition to the normal [columnName]?

Comment: @DiscipleMichael Yes, neither are included. The column is being ignored if duplicated

Comment: Not to be stubborn but if you break the code on the line right after dt was filled, and check it's columns, it doesn't have the dupe columns?